# Vba: error Method 'AutoFilterMode' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

With your help i have this script that: in sheet "ANAF CONTURI" (where i input data) based on a criteria on column G (="DA") it filters and copies the results into a existing sheet named "ANAF BANCI" on a range starting from C2.

Where i input the data i made also a button to execute the macro (its on A1, and on A2 headers).

I get this error when it's trying to remove the filters:

**Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'AutoFilterMode' of object '_Worksheet' failed.**

and then crashes. (on some exceptions it works fine..without any modifications)

btw: sheet8 is actually "ANAF CONTURI"

**This is my code, please help :**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' TRIAZA INFORMATIA INTRODUSA SI O INAINTEAZA SPRE PRELUCRARE IN ANAF BANCI
Sheet8.Unprotect Password:="online07"


Sheets("ANAF BANCI").Range("C2:H1000").ClearContents


    With Sheets("ANAF CONTURI") '<--| reference your sheet

        With .Range("G2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "A:G" range from row 1 down to column "A" last not empty row
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Da" ''<--| filter referenced range on its 7th column (i.e. column "G") with "Da" values
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 6).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ANAF BANCI").Range("C2")
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Sheet8.Range("A3:F20000").Locked = False
    Sheet8.Protect Password:="online07"

End Sub
```

Comment: Also tried with If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData and it also crashed only difference was that it said "Showalldata" etc etc. in the error msg.

Comment: also tried in order to remove filters with succes : Range("A2:G2").Select
    Range("G2").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData ' it worked 4-5 times then failed again ! ...

Comment: Also removed the button and now says : The object invoked has now disconnected from its clients. (still when it attempts to remove filters). Then crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I added this instead of   .AutoFilterMode = False and it seems to work till now:

```
       If (Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").AutoFilterMode And Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").FilterMode) Or Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").FilterMode Then
  Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").ShowAllData
  End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen AutoFilter cause a lot of errors when you incorrectly assume that the sheet is already filtered or vice versa- without knowing how your source data is formatted, testing if `targetSheet.AutoFilterMode = true` might be able to avoid the errors you keep getting.

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode