# VBA Excel - Method "AutoFilterMode" of object '_Worksheet" failed

Tags: excel, vba

May I ask why am I getting this error?

> Method "AutoFilterMode" of object '_Worksheet" failed

Here's the code:

```
Sub del_stud()

    LRN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value
    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws1 In Sheets(Array("STUDENTS_INFO", "N-Q1", "N-Q2", "N-Q3", "N-Q4", "N-D", _
    "JK-Q1", "JK-Q2", "JK-Q3", "JK-Q4", "JK-D", "SK-Q1", "SK-Q2", "SK-Q3", "SK-Q4", "SK-D", _
    "CERTIFICATION"))
    
        With ws1.Cells(8, 3).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter 2, LRN
            .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
            ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    Next ws1
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value = ""

End Sub
```

When I clicked the debug button, the highlighted line is `ws1.AutoFilterMode = False`. As I observed, the `Filter` in the `STUDENTS_INFO` sheet is enabled so all the data are hidden. Note that, my workbook or sheets are **protected**.

Comment: Does it stop at the first Worksheet ("STUDENTS_INFO") or does it stop later? The AutoFilterMode can´t be set to False if there already is no filter. You may have to set an autofilter to make it work.

Comment: @snenson I tried to use this solution and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/41695113/15080594